# How to add Drag and Drop to JLabel which contains a image?

Tags: java, user-interface

```
    p1label.setIcon(p1icon);
    p2label.setIcon(p2icon);
    p3label.setIcon(p3icon);
    p4label.setIcon(p4icon);

    p1label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("p1"));
    p2label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("p2"));
    p3label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("p3"));
    p4label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("p4"));

    MouseMotionListener mouseAction = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            JComponent label = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            TransferHandler th = label.getTransferHandler();
            th.exportAsDrag(label,e,TransferHandler.COPY);
        }
    };

    p1label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
    p2label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
    p3label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
    p4label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
```

Here is my code to add a mouseMotionListener to a JLabel. I want the player to drag one of icon and move it anywhere else. However, none of the imaged moved a bit and nothing happened(no error mesg either).

I am still a newbie to Java GUI. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    p1label.setIcon(p1icon);
    p2label.setIcon(p2icon);
    p3label.setIcon(p3icon);
    p4label.setIcon(p4icon);

    MouseMotionListener mouseAction = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            JComponent label = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            label.setLocation(label.getLocation().x + e.getX(), label.getLocation().y + e.getY());
        }
    };

    p1label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
    p2label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
    p3label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
    p4label.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAction);
```

I changed the dragged method to setLocation instead of using a TransferHandler. It works great! Hope this example can help some of you.